# Synonymize [alpinejs] to [alpine.js]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

The tag [alpinejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/alpinejs) seems like an alternative spelling of the more widely used [alpine.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/alpine.js) one.

Since the latter does have more questions, have a tag info already and is [the branded spelling of the framework](https://alpinejs.dev), it seems logical to me that the synonym goes that way around.

Your thoughts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I did some internet searching and failed to find another "AlpineJS".  I checked a few random questions tagged [alpinejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/alpinejs) and they all either had the same `x-whatever` attributes shown on https://alpinejs.dev/, or had [no JavaScript whatsoever](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70693498/208273) (there was more than one of these...).

I've concluded they're the same thing, and created the synonym.  Since no one yelled at me in the week or so that this post was up, I've gone ahead and merged the tags.